# play 2.0 deployment on heroku - compile timeout

Tags: java, heroku, playframework, playframework-2.0

I am having a time-out while deploying the standard out of the box play 2 java app on heroku.
This compiler stops at a different location each time suggesting there is no problem with a specific resolve line.
Here is a real long output of the push command -

```
git push heroku master
Enter passphrase for key '/home/nimish/.ssh/id_rsa': 
Initializing repository, done.
Counting objects: 32, done.
Delta compression using up to 2 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (26/26), done.
Writing objects: 100% (32/32), 161.02 KiB, done.
Total 32 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)

-----> Play 2.x - Java app detected
-----> Installing OpenJDK 1.6...done
-----> Downloading SBT...done
-----> Running: sbt compile stage
       Getting org.scala-sbt sbt 0.13.0 ...
       downloading http://s3pository.heroku.com/ivy-typesafe-releases/org.scala-sbt/sbt/0.13.0/jars/sbt.jar ...
        [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-sbt#sbt;0.13.0!sbt.jar (263ms)
       downloading http://s3pository.heroku.com/ivy-typesafe-releases/org.scala-sbt/main/0.13.0/jars/main.jar ...
        [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-sbt#main;0.13.0!main.jar (5324ms)
       downloading http://s3pository.heroku.com/ivy-typesafe-releases/org.scala-sbt/compiler-interface/0.13.0/jars/compiler-interface-bin.jar ...
        [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-sbt#compiler-interface;0.13.0!compiler-interface-bin.jar (173ms)
       downloading http://s3pository.heroku.com/ivy-typesafe-releases/org.scala-sbt/compiler-interface/0.13.0/jars/compiler-interface-src.jar ...
        [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-sbt#compiler-interface;0.13.0!compiler-interface-src.jar (153ms)
       downloading http://s3pository.heroku.com/ivy-typesafe-releases/org.scala-sbt/precompiled-2_8_2/0.13.0/jars/compiler-interface-bin.jar ...
        [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-sbt#precompiled-2_8_2;0.13.0!compiler-interface-bin.jar (247ms)
       downloading http://s3pository.heroku.com/ivy-typesafe-releases/org.scala-sbt/precompiled-2_9_2/0.13.0/jars/compiler-interface-bin.jar ...
        [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-sbt#precompiled-2_9_2;0.13.0!compiler-interface-bin.jar (220ms)
       downloading http://s3pository.heroku.com/ivy-typesafe-releases/org.scala-sbt/precompiled-2_9_3/0.13.0/jars/compiler-interface-bin.jar ...
        [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-sbt#precompiled-2_9_3;0.13.0!compiler-interface-bin.jar (370ms)
       downloading http://s3pository.heroku.com/ivy-typesafe-releases/org.scala-sbt/actions/0.13.0/jars/actions.jar ...
        [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-sbt#actions;0.13.0!actions.jar (320ms)
       downloading http://s3pository.heroku.com/ivy-typesafe-releases/org.scala-sbt/main-settings/0.13.0/jars/main-settings.jar ...
        [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-sbt#main-settings;0.13.0!main-settings.jar (291ms)
       downloading http://s3pository.heroku.com/ivy-typesafe-releases/org.scala-sbt/interface/0.13.0/jars/interface.jar ...
        [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-sbt#interface;0.13.0!interface.jar (156ms)
       downloading http://s3pository.heroku.com/ivy-typesafe-releases/org.scala-sbt/io/0.13.0/jars/io.jar ...
        [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-sbt#io;0.13.0!io.jar (378ms)
       downloading http://s3pository.heroku.com/ivy-typesafe-releases/org.scala-sbt/ivy/0.13.0/jars/ivy.jar ...
        [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-sbt#ivy;0.13.0!ivy.jar (362ms)
       downloading http://s3pository.heroku.com/ivy-typesafe-releases/org.scala-sbt/launcher-interface/0.13.0/jars/launcher-interface.jar ...
        [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-sbt#launcher-interface;0.13.0!launcher-interface.jar (145ms)
       downloading http://s3pository.heroku.com/ivy-typesafe-releases/org.scala-sbt/logging/0.13.0/jars/logging.jar ...
        [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-sbt#logging;0.13.0!logging.jar (5321ms)
       downloading http://s3pository.heroku.com/ivy-typesafe-releases/org.scala-sbt/process/0.13.0/jars/process.jar ...
        [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-sbt#process;0.13.0!process.jar (335ms)
       downloading http://s3pository.heroku.com/ivy-typesafe-releases/org.scala-sbt/run/0.13.0/jars/run.jar ...
        [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-sbt#run;0.13.0!run.jar (172ms)
       downloading http://s3pository.heroku.com/ivy-typesafe-releases/org.scala-sbt/command/0.13.0/jars/command.jar ...
        [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-sbt#command;0.13.0!command.jar (361ms)
       downloading http://s3pository.heroku.com/ivy-typesafe-releases/org.scala-sbt/classpath/0.13.0/jars/classpath.jar ...
        [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-sbt#classpath;0.13.0!classpath.jar (272ms)
       downloading http://s3pository.heroku.com/ivy-typesafe-releases/org.scala-sbt/completion/0.13.0/jars/completion.jar ...
        [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-sbt#completion;0.13.0!completion.jar (199ms)
       downloading http://s3pository.heroku.com/ivy-typesafe-releases/org.scala-sbt/api/0.13.0/jars/api.jar ...
        [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-sbt#api;0.13.0!api.jar (327ms)
       downloading http://s3pository.heroku.com/ivy-typesafe-releases/org.scala-sbt/compiler-integration/0.13.0/jars/compiler-integration.jar ...
        [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-sbt#compiler-integration;0.13.0!compiler-integration.jar (170ms)
       downloading http://s3pository.heroku.com/ivy-typesafe-releases/org.scala-sbt/compiler-ivy-integration/0.13.0/jars/compiler-ivy-integration.jar ...
        [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-sbt#compiler-ivy-integration;0.13.0!compiler-ivy-integration.jar (225ms)
       downloading http://s3pository.heroku.com/ivy-typesafe-releases/org.scala-sbt/relation/0.13.0/jars/relation.jar ...
        [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-sbt#relation;0.13.0!relation.jar (5144ms)
       downloading http://s3pository.heroku.com/ivy-typesafe-releases/org.scala-sbt/task-system/0.13.0/jars/task-system.jar ...
        [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-sbt#task-system;0.13.0!task-system.jar (220ms)
       downloading http://s3pository.heroku.com/ivy-typesafe-releases/org.scala-sbt/tasks/0.13.0/jars/tasks.jar ...
        [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-sbt#tasks;0.13.0!tasks.jar (242ms)
       downloading http://s3pository.heroku.com/ivy-typesafe-releases/org.scala-sbt/tracking/0.13.0/jars/tracking.jar ...
        [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-sbt#tracking;0.13.0!tracking.jar (162ms)
       downloading http://s3pository.heroku.com/ivy-typesafe-releases/org.scala-sbt/testing/0.13.0/jars/testing.jar ...
        [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-sbt#testing;0.13.0!testing.jar (151ms)
       downloading http://s3pository.heroku.com/ivy-typesafe-releases/org.scala-sbt/control/0.13.0/jars/control.jar ...
        [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-sbt#control;0.13.0!control.jar (5202ms)
       downloading http://s3pository.heroku.com/maven-central/org/scala-lang/scala-reflect/2.10.2/scala-reflect-2.10.2.jar ...
        [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-lang#scala-reflect;2.10.2!scala-reflect.jar (5279ms)
       downloading http://s3pository.heroku.com/ivy-typesafe-releases/org.scala-sbt/collections/0.13.0/jars/collections.jar ...
        [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-sbt#collections;0.13.0!collections.jar (210ms)
       downloading http://s3pository.heroku.com/maven-central/jline/jline/2.11/jline-2.11.jar ...
        [SUCCESSFUL ] jline#jline;2.11!jline.jar (157ms)
       downloading http://s3pository.heroku.com/ivy-typesafe-releases/org.scala-sbt/incremental-compiler/0.13.0/jars/incremental-compiler.jar ...
        [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-sbt#incremental-compiler;0.13.0!incremental-compiler.jar (188ms)
       downloading http://s3pository.heroku.com/ivy-typesafe-releases/org.scala-sbt/compile/0.13.0/jars/compile.jar ...
        [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-sbt#compile;0.13.0!compile.jar (148ms)
       downloading http://s3pository.heroku.com/ivy-typesafe-releases/org.scala-sbt/persist/0.13.0/jars/persist.jar ...
        [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-sbt#persist;0.13.0!persist.jar (160ms)
       downloading http://s3pository.heroku.com/ivy-typesafe-releases/org.scala-sbt/classfile/0.13.0/jars/classfile.jar ...
        [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-sbt#classfile;0.13.0!classfile.jar (179ms)
       downloading http://typesafe.artifactoryonline.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scala-tools.sbinary/sbinary_2.10/0.4.2/jars/sbinary_2.10.jar ...
        [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-tools.sbinary#sbinary_2.10;0.4.2!sbinary_2.10.jar (144ms)
       downloading http://s3pository.heroku.com/ivy-typesafe-releases/org.scala-sbt/cross/0.13.0/jars/cross.jar ...
        [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-sbt#cross;0.13.0!cross.jar (127ms)
       downloading http://s3pository.heroku.com/maven-central/org/apache/ivy/ivy/2.3.0-rc1/ivy-2.3.0-rc1.jar ...
        [SUCCESSFUL ] org.apache.ivy#ivy;2.3.0-rc1!ivy.jar (317ms)
       downloading http://s3pository.heroku.com/maven-central/com/jcraft/jsch/0.1.46/jsch-0.1.46.jar ...
        [SUCCESSFUL ] com.jcraft#jsch;0.1.46!jsch.jar (175ms)
       downloading http://s3pository.heroku.com/ivy-typesafe-releases/org.scala-sbt/cache/0.13.0/jars/cache.jar ...
        [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-sbt#cache;0.13.0!cache.jar (467ms)
       downloading http://s3pository.heroku.com/ivy-typesafe-releases/org.scala-sbt/test-agent/0.13.0/jars/test-agent.jar ...
        [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-sbt#test-agent;0.13.0!test-agent.jar (147ms)
       downloading http://s3pository.heroku.com/maven-central/org/scala-sbt/test-interface/1.0/test-interface-1.0.jar ...
        [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-sbt#test-interface;1.0!test-interface.jar (108ms)
       downloading http://s3pository.heroku.com/ivy-typesafe-releases/org.scala-sbt/apply-macro/0.13.0/jars/apply-macro.jar ...
        [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-sbt#apply-macro;0.13.0!apply-macro.jar (191ms)
       :: retrieving :: org.scala-sbt#boot-app
        confs: [default]
        43 artifacts copied, 0 already retrieved (12440kB/103ms)
       Getting Scala 2.10.2 (for sbt)...
       downloading http://s3pository.heroku.com/maven-central/org/scala-lang/scala-compiler/2.10.2/scala-compiler-2.10.2.jar ...
        [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-lang#scala-compiler;2.10.2!scala-compiler.jar (1716ms)
       downloading http://s3pository.heroku.com/maven-central/org/scala-lang/scala-library/2.10.2/scala-library-2.10.2.jar ...
        [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-lang#scala-library;2.10.2!scala-library.jar (1450ms)
       downloading http://s3pository.heroku.com/maven-central/org/scala-lang/jline/2.10.2/jline-2.10.2.jar ...
        [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-lang#jline;2.10.2!jline.jar (170ms)
       downloading http://s3pository.heroku.com/maven-central/org/fusesource/jansi/jansi/1.4/jansi-1.4.jar ...
        [SUCCESSFUL ] org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.4!jansi.jar (94ms)
       :: retrieving :: org.scala-sbt#boot-scala
        confs: [default]
        5 artifacts copied, 0 already retrieved (24390kB/50ms)
       [info] Loading project definition from /tmp/scala_buildpack_build_dir/project
       [warn] Multiple resolvers having different access mechanism configured with same name 'typesafe-ivy-releases'. To avoid conflict, Remove duplicate project resolvers (`resolvers`) or rename publishing resolver (`publishTo`).
       [info] Set current project to ExampleBootStrap (in build file:/tmp/scala_buildpack_build_dir/)
       [info] Updating {file:/tmp/scala_buildpack_build_dir/}scala_buildpack_build_dir...
       [info] Resolving org.scala-lang#scala-library;2.10.2 ...
       [info] Resolving com.typesafe.play#play-java-jdbc_2.10;2.2.1 ...
       [info] Resolving com.typesafe.play#play-jdbc_2.10;2.2.1 ...
       [info] Resolving com.typesafe.play#play_2.10;2.2.1 ...
       [info] Resolving com.typesafe.play#sbt-link;2.2.1 ...
       [info] Resolving org.javassist#javassist;3.18.0-GA ...
       [info] Resolving com.typesafe.play#play-exceptions;2.2.1 ...
       [info] Resolving com.typesafe.play#templates_2.10;2.2.1 ...
       [info] Resolving com.github.scala-incubator.io#scala-io-file_2.10;0.4.2 ...
       [info] Resolving com.github.scala-incubator.io#scala-io-core_2.10;0.4.2 ...
       [info] Resolving com.jsuereth#scala-arm_2.10;1.3 ...
       [info] Resolving com.typesafe.play#play-iteratees_2.10;2.2.1 ...
       [info] Resolving org.scala-stm#scala-stm_2.10;0.7 ...
       [info] Resolving com.typesafe#config;1.0.2 ...
       [info] Resolving com.typesafe.play#play-json_2.10;2.2.1 ...
       [info] Resolving com.typesafe.play#play-functional_2.10;2.2.1 ...
       [info] Resolving com.typesafe.play#play-datacommons_2.10;2.2.1 ...
       [info] Resolving joda-time#joda-time;2.2 ...
       [info] Resolving org.joda#joda-convert;1.3.1 ...
       [info] Resolving com.fasterxml.jackson.core#jackson-annotations;2.2.2 ...
       [info] Resolving com.fasterxml#oss-parent;10 ...
       [info] Resolving com.fasterxml.jackson.core#jackson-core;2.2.2 ...
       [info] Resolving com.fasterxml#oss-parent;10 ...
       [info] Resolving com.fasterxml.jackson.core#jackson-databind;2.2.2 ...
       [info] Resolving com.fasterxml#oss-parent;10 ...
       [info] Resolving org.scala-lang#scala-reflect;2.10.2 ...
       [info] Resolving io.netty#netty;3.7.0.Final ...
       [info] Resolving org.sonatype.oss#oss-parent;7 ...
       [info] Resolving com.typesafe.netty#netty-http-pipelining;1.1.2 ...
       [info] Resolving org.slf4j#slf4j-api;1.7.5 ...
       [info] Resolving org.slf4j#slf4j-parent;1.7.5 ...
       [info] Resolving org.slf4j#jul-to-slf4j;1.7.5 ...
       [info] Resolving org.slf4j#slf4j-parent;1.7.5 ...
       [info] Resolving org.slf4j#jcl-over-slf4j;1.7.5 ...
       [info] Resolving org.slf4j#slf4j-parent;1.7.5 ...
       [info] Resolving ch.qos.logback#logback-core;1.0.13 ...
       [info] Resolving ch.qos.logback#logback-parent;1.0.13 ...
       [info] Resolving ch.qos.logback#logback-classic;1.0.13 ...
       [info] Resolving ch.qos.logback#logback-parent;1.0.13 ...
       [info] Resolving com.typesafe.akka#akka-actor_2.10;2.2.0 ...
       [info] Resolving com.typesafe.akka#akka-slf4j_2.10;2.2.0 ...
       [info] Resolving org.apache.commons#commons-lang3;3.1 ...
       [info] Resolving org.apache.commons#commons-parent;22 ...
       [info] Resolving org.apache#apache;9 ...
       [info] Resolving com.ning#async-http-client;1.7.18 ...
       [info] Resolving org.sonatype.oss#oss-parent;5 ...
       [info] Resolving oauth.signpost#signpost-core;1.2.1.2 ...
       [info] Resolving oauth.signpost#oauth-signpost;1.2.1.2 ...
       [info] Resolving commons-codec#commons-codec;1.3 ...
       [info] Resolving oauth.signpost#signpost-commonshttp4;1.2.1.2 ...
       [info] Resolving oauth.signpost#oauth-signpost;1.2.1.2 ...
       [info] Resolving org.apache.httpcomponents#httpcore;4.0.1 ...
       [info] Resolving org.apache.httpcomponents#httpcomponents-core;4.0.1 ...
       [info] Resolving org.apache.httpcomponents#project;4.0 ...
       [info] Resolving org.apache.httpcomponents#httpclient;4.0.1 ...
       [info] Resolving org.apache.httpcomponents#httpcomponents-client;4.0.1 ...
       [info] Resolving org.apache.httpcomponents#project;4.0 ...
       [info] Resolving commons-logging#commons-logging;1.1.1 ...
       [info] Resolving org.apache.commons#commons-parent;5 ...
       [info] Resolving org.apache#apache;4 ...
       [info] Resolving xerces#xercesImpl;2.11.0 ...
       [info] Resolving xml-apis#xml-apis;1.4.01 ...
       [info] Resolving javax.transaction#jta;1.1 ...
       [info] Resolving com.jolbox#bonecp;0.8.0.RELEASE ...
       [info] Resolving com.jolbox#bonecp-parent;0.8.0.RELEASE ...
       [info] Resolving com.google.guava#guava;14.0.1 ...
       [info] Resolving com.h2database#h2;1.3.172 ...
       [info] Resolving tyrex#tyrex;1.0.1 ...
       [info] Resolving com.typesafe.play#play-java_2.10;2.2.1 ...
       [info] Resolving org.yaml#snakeyaml;1.12 ...
       [info] Resolving org.hibernate#hibernate-validator;5.0.1.Final ...
       [info] Resolving org.hibernate#hibernate-validator-parent;5.0.1.Final ...
       [info] Resolving org.jboss.arquillian#arquillian-bom;1.0.2.Final ...
       [info] Resolving org.jboss.shrinkwrap#shrinkwrap-bom;1.0.1 ...
       [info] Resolving org.jboss.shrinkwrap.resolver#shrinkwrap-resolver-bom;1.0.0-beta-7 ...
       [info] Resolving org.jboss.shrinkwrap.descriptors#shrinkwrap-descriptors-bom;2.0.0-alpha-3 ...
       [info] Resolving javax.validation#validation-api;1.1.0.Final ...
       [info] Resolving org.jboss.logging#jboss-logging;3.1.1.GA ...
       [info] Resolving org.jboss#jboss-parent;7 ...
       [info] Resolving com.fasterxml#classmate;0.8.0 ...
       [info] Resolving org.sonatype.oss#oss-parent;7 ...
       [info] Resolving org.springframework#spring-context;3.2.3.RELEASE ...
       [info] Resolving org.springframework#spring-core;3.2.3.RELEASE ...
       [info] Resolving org.springframework#spring-beans;3.2.3.RELEASE ...
       [info] Resolving org.reflections#reflections;0.9.8 ...
       [info] Resolving org.reflections#reflections-parent;0.9.8 ...
       [info] Resolving dom4j#dom4j;1.6.1 ...
       [info] Resolving com.google.code.findbugs#jsr305;2.0.1 ...
       [info] Resolving javax.servlet#javax.servlet-api;3.0.1 ...
       [info] Resolving net.java#jvnet-parent;1 ...
       [info] Resolving com.typesafe.play#play-java-ebean_2.10;2.2.1 ...
       [info] Resolving org.avaje.ebeanorm#avaje-ebeanorm;3.2.2 ...
       [info] Resolving org.avaje#avaje-javaparent;1.2 ...
       [info] Resolving org.avaje#avaje-parent;1.2 ...
       [info] Resolving org.sonatype.oss#oss-parent;7 ...
       [info] Resolving org.avaje.ebeanorm#avaje-ebeanorm-agent;3.2.1 ...
       [info] Resolving org.hibernate.javax.persistence#hibernate-jpa-2.0-api;1.0.1.Final ...
       [info] Resolving com.typesafe.play#play-cache_2.10;2.2.1 ...
       [info] Resolving net.sf.ehcache#ehcache-core;2.6.6 ...
       [info] Resolving net.sf.ehcache#ehcache-parent;2.3 ...
       [info] Resolving com.typesafe.play#play-test_2.10;2.2.1 ...
       [info] Resolving junit#junit;4.11 ...
       [info] Resolving org.hamcrest#hamcrest-core;1.3 ...
       [info] Resolving org.hamcrest#hamcrest-parent;1.3 ...
       [info] Resolving org.specs2#specs2_2.10;2.1.1 ...
       [info] Resolving org.scalaz#scalaz-core_2.10;7.0.2 ...
       [info] Resolving org.scalaz#scalaz-concurrent_2.10;7.0.2 ...
       [info] Resolving org.scalaz#scalaz-effect_2.10;7.0.2 ...
       [info] Resolving com.novocode#junit-interface;0.10 ...
       [info] Resolving org.scala-tools.testing#test-interface;0.5 ...
       [info] Resolving org.fluentlenium#fluentlenium-festassert;0.8.0 ...
       [info] Resolving org.fluentlenium#fluentlenium-parent;0.8.0 ...
       [info] Resolving org.sonatype.oss#oss-parent;7 ...
       [info] Resolving org.fluentlenium#fluentlenium-core;0.8.0 ...
       [info] Resolving org.fluentlenium#fluentlenium-parent;0.8.0 ...
       [info] Resolving org.seleniumhq.selenium#selenium-java;2.32.0 ...
       [info] Resolving org.seleniumhq.selenium#selenium-parent;2.32.0 ...
       [info] Resolving org.seleniumhq.selenium#selenium-android-driver;2.32.0 ...
       [info] Resolving org.seleniumhq.selenium#selenium-parent;2.32.0 ...
       [info] Resolving org.seleniumhq.selenium#selenium-remote-driver;2.32.0 ...
       [info] Resolving org.seleniumhq.selenium#selenium-parent;2.32.0 ...
       [info] Resolving cglib#cglib-nodep;2.1_3 ...
       [info] Resolving org.json#json;20080701 ...
       [info] Resolving org.seleniumhq.selenium#selenium-api;2.32.0 ...
       [info] Resolving org.seleniumhq.selenium#selenium-parent;2.32.0 ...
       [info] Resolving org.apache.httpcomponents#httpclient;4.2.1 ...
       [info] Resolving org.apache.httpcomponents#httpcomponents-client;4.2.1 ...
       [info] Resolving org.apache.httpcomponents#project;6 ...
       [info] Resolving org.apache.httpcomponents#httpcore;4.2.1 ...
       [info] Resolving org.apache.httpcomponents#httpcomponents-core;4.2.1 ...
       [info] Resolving org.apache.httpcomponents#project;6 ...
       [info] Resolving commons-codec#commons-codec;1.6 ...
       [info] Resolving org.apache.commons#commons-parent;22 ...
       [info] Resolving org.apache.commons#commons-exec;1.1 ...
       [info] Resolving org.apache.commons#commons-parent;17 ...
       [info] Resolving org.apache#apache;7 ...
       [info] Resolving net.java.dev.jna#jna;3.4.0 ...
       [info] Resolving net.java.dev.jna#platform;3.4.0 ...
       [info] Resolving org.seleniumhq.selenium#selenium-chrome-driver;2.32.0 ...
       [info] Resolving org.seleniumhq.selenium#selenium-parent;2.32.0 ...
       [info] Resolving org.seleniumhq.selenium#selenium-htmlunit-driver;2.32.0 ...
       [info] Resolving org.seleniumhq.selenium#selenium-parent;2.32.0 ...
       [info] Resolving net.sourceforge.htmlunit#htmlunit;2.12 ...
       [info] Resolving xalan#xalan;2.7.1 ...
       [info] Resolving org.apache#apache;4 ...
       [info] Resolving xalan#serializer;2.7.1 ...
       [info] Resolving org.apache#apache;4 ...
       [info] Resolving commons-collections#commons-collections;3.2.1 ...
       [info] Resolving org.apache.commons#commons-parent;9 ...
       [info] Resolving org.apache#apache;4 ...
       [info] Resolving org.apache.httpcomponents#httpmime;4.2.3 ...
       [info] Resolving org.apache.httpcomponents#httpcomponents-client;4.2.3 ...
       [info] Resolving org.apache.httpcomponents#project;6 ...
       [info] Resolving net.sourceforge.htmlunit#htmlunit-core-js;2.12 ...
       [info] Resolving net.sourceforge.nekohtml#nekohtml;1.9.18 ...
       [info] Resolving net.sourceforge.cssparser#cssparser;0.9.9 ...
       [info] Resolving org.sonatype.oss#oss-parent;7 ...
       [info] Resolving org.w3c.css#sac;1.3 ...
       [info] Resolving commons-io#commons-io;2.2 ...
       [info] Resolving org.apache.commons#commons-parent;24 ...
       [info] Resolving org.eclipse.jetty#jetty-websocket;8.1.9.v20130131 ...
       [info] Resolving org.eclipse.jetty#jetty-project;8.1.9.v20130131 ...
       [info] Resolving org.eclipse.jetty#jetty-parent;20 ...
       [info] Resolving org.eclipse.jetty#jetty-util;8.1.9.v20130131 ...
       [info] Resolving org.eclipse.jetty#jetty-project;8.1.9.v20130131 ...
       [info] Resolving org.eclipse.jetty#jetty-io;8.1.9.v20130131 ...
       [info] Resolving org.eclipse.jetty#jetty-project;8.1.9.v20130131 ...
       [info] Resolving org.eclipse.jetty#jetty-http;8.1.9.v20130131 ...
       [info] Resolving org.eclipse.jetty#jetty-project;8.1.9.v20130131 ...
       [info] Resolving org.seleniumhq.selenium#selenium-firefox-driver;2.32.0 ...
       [info] Resolving org.seleniumhq.selenium#selenium-parent;2.32.0 ...
       [info] Resolving org.seleniumhq.selenium#selenium-ie-driver;2.32.0 ...
       [info] Resolving org.seleniumhq.selenium#selenium-parent;2.32.0 ...
       [info] Resolving org.seleniumhq.selenium#selenium-iphone-driver;2.32.0 ...
       [info] Resolving org.seleniumhq.selenium#selenium-parent;2.32.0 ...
       [info] Resolving org.seleniumhq.selenium#selenium-safari-driver;2.32.0 ...
       [info] Resolving org.seleniumhq.selenium#selenium-parent;2.32.0 ...
       [info] Resolving org.webbitserver#webbit;0.4.14 ...
       [info] Resolving org.sonatype.oss#oss-parent;6 ...
       [info] Resolving org.seleniumhq.selenium#selenium-support;2.32.0 ...
       [info] Resolving org.seleniumhq.selenium#selenium-parent;2.32.0 ...
       [info] Resolving org.easytesting#fest-assert;1.4 ...
       [info] Resolving org.easytesting#fest;1.0.8 ...
       [info] Resolving org.easytesting#fest-util;1.1.6 ...
       [info] Resolving org.easytesting#fest;1.0.8 ...
       [info] Resolving com.typesafe.play#play-docs_2.10;2.2.1 ...
       [info] Resolving org.scala-lang#scala-library;2.10.0 ...

 !     Timed out compiling Play 2.x - Java app (15 minutes)
 !     See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/slug-compiler#time-limit

To git@heroku.com:enigmatic-dusk-7498.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:enigmatic-dusk-7498.git'
```

Comment: It is really surprising that it's taking 15 minutes to get that far.  I'd suggest filing a support ticket with Heroku.

Comment: I have done so lets see. Notably, it takes whole lot of time at this step. Dunno if it implies anything . Multiple resolvers having different access mechanism configured with same name 'typesafe-ivy-releases'. To avoid conflict, Remove duplicate project resolvers (`resolvers`) or rename publishing resolver (`publishTo`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok So this got resolved when heroku increased my compile time. It was getting compiled in close to 20 mins. 
They suggested upgrading to JDK 7, which i did as they said it can cause this.
I suggest others to try that out as well if you are on 6. 
However it was the compile-time extension that did the trick to me.